# How do I check the size of a directory?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

[image]

How do I check the size of my webroot directory?

While I try the command `df -h /var/www/`, the used space showed was the entire server.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Or just [use a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Linux+How+do+I+check+the+size+of+a+directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `du -sh file_path` (in this case /var/www).
For more information on `du`, see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du).

**Explanation**

- **du** (**d**isc **u**sage) command estimates file_path space usage
- The options `-sh` means (from [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du))

```
 -s, --summarize
        display only a total for each argument

 -h, --human-readable
        print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```